# How do I ask questions using a switch and have a final solution based on whatever the user selected from the switch?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

So I'm trying to do this. I have a program that runs a switch. From the switch you can select 1, 2, 3, or 4, and for each selection is a shape. You enter the necessary entry to calculate the area of said shape. I have all 4 of these done.

Now the final part of the switch will need to take what the user selected and calculate the TOTAL AREA. I can't figure out how to only include user selections in this final part of the switch.

What I mean by this is, if the user selected circle, and triangle but not rectangle or square. How do I let the final switch know that the user ONLY selected triangle and circle and not the other two?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I have changed it now. Here is my updated code. Currently running into this issue. It counts everything, but my `if else` statement.

**EDIT2: 
SOLVED.**

The issue I had (in case anyone ever runs into this which I expect most won't), is I had to add `choices.push_back(2);` to each case then the vector calls it properly in the if loop in case 5.

`using namespace std;

double SLength, SWidth, SArea, RLength, RWidth, RArea, radius, CArea, base, height, TArea, total_area, labor, carpet, total, taxcost; 
const double pi = 3.14; 
const double cost = 2.45;
const double tax = .085;
vector<int> choices;


void AreaSquare() //creating an equation to be called to in my switch for fahrenheit conversion 
{   
        SArea = pow(SLength,2.0); 
}

void AreaRectangle() //creating an equation to be called to in my switch for fahrenheit conversion 
{   
        RArea = (RWidth * RLength); 
}

void AreaCircle() //creating an equation to be called to in my switch for fahrenheit conversion 
{   
        CArea = pi * pow(radius,2.0);  
}

void AreaTriangle() //creating an equation to be called to in my switch for fahrenheit conversion 
{   
        TArea = 0.5 * base * height;  
}



int main()
{



    unsigned short choice;

    do 
    {
        cout << "Please choose from the following: " << "\n";
        cout << "1: Square"<< "\n";
        cout << "2: Rectangle"<< "\n";
        cout << "3: Circle"<< "\n";
        cout << "4: Triangle"<< "\n";
        cout << "5: Total Area"<< "\n"; 
        cout << "0: To Exit the Program"<< "\n"; 
        cin >> choice; 
        system ("cls"); 

        switch (choice)
        {

        case 1: 
            cout << "Please enter the Length: ";
            cin >> SLength; 


            AreaSquare();

            cout << "The area of the Square is " << SArea << "\n";
            total_area += SArea;

            system ("pause"); // pauses the program 
            system ("cls"); //clears the screen
            break; 

        case 2: 
            cout << "Please enter the Length: "; 
            cin >> RLength;

            cout << "Please enter the Width: ";
            cin >> RWidth; 

            AreaRectangle(); 

            cout << "The area of the Rectangle is " << RArea<< "\n"; 
            total_area += RArea;

            system ("pause"); // pauses the program 
            system ("cls"); //clears the screen
            break; 


        case 3: 
            cout << "Please enter the Radius of the Circle: "; 
            cin >> radius; 

            AreaCircle(); 

            cout << "The area of the Circle is: " << CArea<< "\n"; 
            total_area += CArea;

            system ("pause"); // pauses the program 
            system ("cls"); //clears the screen
            break;


        case 4: 
            cout << "Please enter the base of the Triangle: "; 
            cin >> base; 

            cout << "Please enter the height of the Triangle: "; 
            cin >> height; 

            AreaTriangle();

            cout << "The area of the Triangle is " << TArea << "\n";
            total_area += TArea;

            system ("pause"); // pauses the program 
            system ("cls"); //clears the screen
            break;


        case 5: 
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++ )
            {
      if ( choices[i] == 1 ) 
      {
          cout << "Shape: Square" << "\n"; 
          cout << "Length: " << SLength << "\n"; 
          cout << "Area: " << SArea << "Square Feet" << "\n"; 

      }
      else if ( choices[i] == 2 ) 
      {
          cout << "Shape: Rectangle" << "\n"; 
          cout << "Length: " << RLength << "\n"; 
          cout << "Width: " << RWidth << "\n";
          cout << "Area: " << RArea << "Square Feet"<< "\n"; 
      }
      else if ( choices[i] == 3 ) 
      {
          cout << "Shape: Circle" << "\n"; 
          cout << "Radius: " << radius << "\n"; 
          cout << "Area: " << CArea << "Square Feet" << "\n"; 
      }
      else if ( choices[i] == 4 ) 
      {
          cout << "Shape: Triangle" << "\n"; 
          cout << "Base: " << base << "\n";
          cout << "Height: " << height << "\n";
          cout << "Area: " << TArea << "Square Feet" << "\n"; 
      }

            }


            labor = (total_area / 50) * 35.72;
            carpet = (total_area * 2.45); 
            taxcost = (labor + carpet) * tax; 
            total = (labor + carpet + taxcost) ;

         cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
         cout << "Total area: $" << total_area << " Square Feet " << "\n"; 
         cout << "Carpet Cost: $" << carpet << "\n"; 
         cout << "Labor cost: $" << labor << "\n"; 
         cout << "Tax: $" << taxcost << "\n"; 
         cout << "Total Cost: $" << total << "\n"; 


        case 0:     //case in case user selects 0 the program will exit
            cout << "Program is terminating..."<< endl; 

            system ("pause");
            return 0;
            break; //causes the prgram to execute the next statement outside the switch


        default: //the third case incase the user enters an invalid option

            cout << "That is not an option!" << endl;
            cout << "Please try again." << endl;

            cout << "\n" << endl;
            cout << "\n" << endl;
            cout << "\n" << endl;

            system ("pause"); // pauses the program 
            system ("cls"); //clears the screen
            break; //causes the program to execute the next statement outside the switch 
        }




        }   while (choice != 0);


}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store them.  You know about vectors?

```
std::vector<int> choices;
```

Then, within each case:, do this:

```
choices.push_back( n ); // where n = the input
```

This is only necessary if you need to know exactly what was chosen and how many times.  If you just need the total area, simply store total area in a variable with proper scope (like choice) and append the area of each shape at each iteration.

EDIT:

Okay, so there's a few ways to do this.  With your given code base, I think the easiest is to store total area in a variable within each case, plus store each choice in a vector (see above).  In case 5:, you need to loop through that vector and show all the previous choices, and outside of that loop, print the total area.

```
case 5:
for ( size_t i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++ ) {
      if ( choices[i] == 0 ) {
           // print out shape associated w/ zero
      } else if ( choice[i] == 1 ) {
           // print out shape associated w/ 1
      }
      //... etc.
 }

 std::cout << "Total area: " << total_area << std:::endl;
```

Comment: I have not interacted with vectors at all. Anyway you would be up to explaining that a bit more?

Comment: Many ways to skin that cat (and I can't at the moment but I can get to it).  One thing I can't figure out is where you are printing out the total area.

Comment: Would this work? Assigning a string output then pass it to each user-defined function as a reference such that the information of the shape can be added together to the output to display them in main(). For example, double areaSquare(string& output). If so how exactly would I code this in my situation?

Comment: Ah ok. So that would print out the correct shape from the selection above. So total area would be stored inside each case and just not be used at all until it is called to in case 5 correct? And then once you go through that for loop that prints out the Shape and then the users input for length and width. Then it dose it again for each selection that isused. Then at the end we cout Total area. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: That's basically it.  You can also print out the total are as you go. I think a better solution (which gives more flexibility) is to write a separate function which will take an input (shape type) and return the area.  You can call that within each switch statement, as well as at the end.  You can print out whatever you want when you call them.

Comment: Ok man so I have tried incorporating this but ran into an issue. I am not sure what is going on but I think I don't fully understand your answer. Your code gives me the error for choices.size(); and says undefined so I'm assuming I have to define it but I'm not sure where or how I'm defining this. Also to store total area in each case would I just do  areaTotal += Sarea/TArea/ETC...; inside of each case?

Comment: And to store the Choice I am not sure if I did it right or not I've never used vectors. I basically did this. Vector<int> choice; So should I make a vector for each choice? Like Vector<int> choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4; ???Is that the error with my choices.size(); being undefined?

Comment: Hey man, I edited the code above to show what I now have. Everything compiles successfully but I am having ONE ISSUE. In my case 5 the if else statement you setup that I tried setting up is not couting anything. So nothing from the users selections is showing up. So if a user selects square. It is successfully adding up the total area of a square and a rectangle but it is not showing the users selection beforehand. Any idea what I did incorrectly?

Comment: No problem -- welcome to C++. ;)  Sorry for the late reply, I wound up getting busy last night. Anywho, you got it and that's what matters.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your area* variables are global, they are initialized to 0 by default. So the simplest approach is to add all the area* variables.

I can tell you are learning to program so I will merely say that is a lot of scope for improvements in this program.

Comment: Haha yes, trying to teach myself to program actually. Any pointers or tips would be very welcome and appreciated.

Comment: And here is my thing. I want it specifically to have this output     Shape :   RECTANGLE
Length:   11.2 feetP
Width :   10.4 feet
Area    :   116.48 square feet
Shape :   SQUARE
Side    :   10.50 feet
Area   :   110.25 square feet
Total of the area: 226.73 (square feet)

Comment: So it would, in the final selection, call back to whatever the user put in, and it would show their selections. IE, if they select Rectangle it would show. RECTANGLE: and give all the information they put in about the rectangle. Then it would show the circle if they selected it. Finally it would add the area of the two together. I just can't figure out how to write an equation that only uses what the user enters. Or how to write the code that displays the users entry.

Comment: @ChristopherStobie you should invest some time into learning how switch statements work and how they are structured.

Comment: Would this work? Assigning a string output then pass it to each user-defined function as a reference such that the information of the shape can be added together to the output to display them in main(). For example, double areaSquare(string& output). If so how exactly would I code this in my situation?

Comment: @ChristopherStobie you are probably blindly jumping in to programming. If you learn the fundamentals first, you won't have so many questions. The program that you are trying to write is extremely simple. In regards to tips all I can suggest is read a book and practice and understand the concept while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ton of issues.  For one, the current state of your program, even without the extra bit you're going for, is already broken with missing break statements and copy-paste errors.  I'm tired and in pain right now, so maybe I'll explain later, but here is a cleaned up version of your program.  The summary is that you don't need globals, if you repeat something across multiple cases in your switch, then that something probably should be done outside of the switch, enums with meaningful names make it easier to tell what you're doing than literals, for loops exist so you don't have to repeat the same code half a dozen times, you only need one return statement, nobody really uses do-while loops if you have control over the starting condition, and you can cache area results in an extra variable.

Edit: I didn't realize you wanted to store the shape selections in addition to the total area, so I've added an std::vector, which is a dynamic array, to store the user selections in.  I've intentionally left out storing the width, height, radius, etc., for two reasons: 1) Now that you've seen how I stored the selections, you should be able to replicate that logic with anything else you want to store, and 2) with procedural programming like what you're doing here, it's more work than it's worth.  Instead, it'd be wiser to start learning about structs and classes at this point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
const double pi = 3.14;

enum Option
{
    Exit=0,
    Square,
    Rectangle,
    Circle,
    Triangle,
    Totals,
    Max
};
const char* const OptionNames[Max] =
{
    "Exit",
    "Square",
    "Rectangle",
    "Circle",
    "Triangle",
    "Total Area"
};

int main()
{
    // Declare a container to store user selections in
    vector<Option> selections;

    // Declare a variable that stores the total area
    double areaTotal = 0;

    // Declare a variable to store the user's input and initialize it to something other than the exit condition
    int userChoice = Totals;

    // While the user hasn't opted to exit
    while (Exit != userChoice)
    {
        // Prompt the user to select a shape
        cout << "Please select a shape:\n";

        // Iterate over all options, starting with square, and display their corresponding names
        for (int i=Square; i<Max; ++i)
        {
            cout << i << ". " << OptionNames[i] << '\n';
        }

        // Show the Exit option last
        cout << Exit << ". " << OptionNames[Exit] << '\n';

        // Take the user's input
        cin >> userChoice;

        // If they entered a shape (not Exit or Total), save their selection
        if (userChoice > Exit && userChoice < Totals)
            selections.push_back(Option(userChoice));   // cast the int to an Option

        // Evaluate the selection
        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case Exit:
            { 
                cout << "Program is terminating...\n";
                break;
                // Nothing else needs to be done here, as we are breaking out of the switch, and the while-loop's exit condition is now met
            }
            case Square:
            {
                cout << "Please enter the length of one side: ";
                double length;
                cin >> length;

                double area = length * length;
                cout << "The area of the Square is " << area << '\n';
                areaTotal += area;

                break;
            }
            case Rectangle:
            {
                cout << "Please enter the length: ";
                double length;
                cin >> length;

                cout << "Please enter the width: ";
                double width;
                cin >> width;

                double area = (length * width);
                cout << "The area of the Rectangle is " << area << '\n';
                areaTotal += area;

                break;
            }
            case Circle:
            {
                cout << "Please enter the radius: ";
                double radius;
                cin >> radius;

                double area = pi * pow(radius, 2.0);
                cout << "The area of the Circle is: " << area << '\n';
                areaTotal += area;

                break;
            }
            case Triangle:
            {
                cout << "Please enter the base: ";
                double base;
                cin >> base;

                cout << "Please enter the hight: ";
                double height;
                cin >> height;

                double area = 0.5 * base * height;
                cout << "The area of the triangle is " << area << '\n';
                areaTotal += area;

                break;
            }
            case Totals:
            {
                cout << "Your selections were:\n";

                // Iterate over all selections except the last one, placing a comma and space after each one
                int i;
                for (i=0; i<selections.size()-1; ++i)
                {
                    cout << OptionNames[selections[i]] << ", ";
                }
                // The last selection goes outside the for-loop, so we can put a newline after it instead of a comma
                cout << OptionNames[selections[i]] << ".\n";

                // Display the total area
                cout << "The total area is: " << areaTotal << '\n';
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                cout << "That is not an option!\n";
                cout << "Please try again.\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for the feedback. I am still very new to all this and trying to teach myself. Ok so in your example your case Totals:  is still missing the info that I need. In Totals: I would need for it to display what shapes the user selected. So if he selected square and circle the case Totals: would display square: length, width, area, Then it would display Circle: Radius, Area. Then it would calculate the total area of just the two selections that the user made. That's actually the part I'm stuck on. I'm working on the answer above but still haven't quite got it figured out.